# Why is a suspended spinning body of liquid prolate?

Tags: centrifugal-force

Instead of a flat disc one would expect the centrifugal forces to push it in..

The body is not in a container but suspended in air spinning horizontally (i.e. left to right or vice-versa) - how to do this could be challenging - but that is not the issue.

**Answer:** It is not prolate: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxyfiBGCwhQ.

Comment: This question is too imprecise to be answered; how spinning? in what container? How is "oval shaped (vertically)"?

Comment: I have updated it, is that suffice?

Comment: Q: "oval shaped (vertically)"? A: Like a rugby ball.

Comment: No ;-) How suspended? If in no-gravity situation, this is mostly a tradeoff between c-f making it a disc and surface tension making it a sphere, but the result is oblate not prolate.

Comment: If the water is not in a container, then its shape is determined by the surrounding gravitational field, very likely pulling downward. Or is this a zero g question? There are other zero g Stack questions of this form, I believe.

Comment: I thought it was prolate? Gravity can be there but would have to allow body to remain suspended - I am not really interested in the distortion it would cause - so zero g is fine.

Comment: I still don't really know what you are asking. Any spinning liquid in any shaped container forms a paraboloid. This is used to make liquid telescopes. Are you asking something about the shape of a spinning uncontained liquid? That would be dynamic and unstable.

Comment: "Are you asking something about the shape of a spinning uncontained liquid?" Yes, and I ask because it is unexpectedly prolate not oblate, or so I thought..

Comment: I "read" that this is about a liquid at zero gravity, but of course the rotation of such a "drop" would not lead to a prolate ellipsoid, but more approach a disk (As I understand "prolate")

Comment: I would have thought so too but I heard otherwise. (one of us must be mixed up, I take prolate to mean like rugby ball, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroid, and oblate to be like a disc..)

Comment: Before someone writing up an answer you might want to glance at the short Wikipedia article on astronomical or nuclear examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate. Does any of this have to do with your question?

Comment: No, the astronomical and nuclear examples do not explain the phenomena...

Comment: The astronomical examples dont? This ends the discussion for me.

Comment: They are involved with low orbits about around heavy masses or electromagnetic forces neither of which would be involved in this case..

Comment: A good general rule: Before asking "why," ask "whether." I'm not convinced that the phenomenon for which you're seeking an explanation actually occurs. Can you give a more specific example, or some sort of evidence that this occurs?

Comment: So, why do You write about "supended in air" although the word microgravity is in the headline of that video? Why d You talk about prolat, although the spinning drops are oblate? Dis You mean to test us?

Comment: it is suspended in air, im sorry i was wrong about the shape - I heard otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't prolate. It's oblate. Centrifugal forces push stuff *out* from the center. Nearby surface elements of the liquid are tugged along by surface tension, flattening out the original shape into a disk.

If something were to take on a prolate shape, there would need to be forces along the axis of rotation, which don't exist for most fluids I can think of, but if you provide a counterexample we could probably explain it. Beyond that, I think you're just confused.

Comment: Did You read the comments to this question? "Everthing was said already, but not by everybody"

Comment: @Georg I don't know what you're so angry about. The original question was "Why does <thing that doesn't exist> exist?" and the only correct answer is, of course, "It doesn't." Even if this was discussed in the comments, stack exchange doesn't work off of comments, it works off of answers.

Comment: If You read the whole thread (including times of answers and comments) You might learn why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about liquids 'suspended in air', but a self-gravitating rotating fluid may take many shapes, not only oblate ones.

Jacobi has shown that at high enough spin rates the familiar oblate shape becomes unstable and turns into a triaxial ellipsoid. At even higher spins another instability appears (this one was described by Poincaré) and the system becomes pear-shaped.